# C# and CreateProcessWithTokenW - Start process with a different users token

Tags: c#, winapi, token

Is there a way to get a different users token and start a process with that token, using `CreateProcessTokenW()`? I need to start a process with another users credentials. How do I get a users token to use for this?

Comment: if you know a process created by that user you can use OpenProcessToken to duplicate that token

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you know the user's credentials. If so you should call [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, from C# it is simpler to use the `UserName` and `Password` properties of [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).